# Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a size of zero for a collection view cell's content view

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Has anyone got this problem with CollectionView?

```
Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a size of zero for a
collection view cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using 
standard size instead.
```

I have added custom CollectionViewCell with xib in CollectionView.

Comment: Did you solved the Problem? I get the same message and can't figure out why...

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are not setting the layout constraints properly in the cell. Try adding top, bottom, left and right constraints to the objects in the cell.